# Getter and Setter for a View

Tags: c++

I have a Getter and a Setter for a view. 
at the moment I am passing a string and checking it. 
and set the data accordingly. It is becoming unwieldy since i have about 50+ items of mixed widgets.

Can you recommend an better solution than the current one i am using.

Code for Setter

```
    void wxfbIntegrationFrame::SetWidgetValue(wxString widget, wxString data)
    {
        if (widget.compare("hours") == 0) { hours->SetValue(data); }
        else if (widget.compare("flowrateon") == 0) { flowrateon->SetValue(data); }
        else if (widget.compare("pressureon") == 0) { pressureon->SetValue(data); }
        else if (widget.compare("flowrateoff") == 0) {      flowrateoff->SetValue(data);    }   
        else if (widget.compare("pressureoff") == 0) {      pressureoff->SetValue(data);    }
        else if (widget.compare("surveynumber") == 0) {     surveynumber->SetValue(data);   }
        else if (widget.compare("warninglabel") == 0) {     warninglabel->SetLabelText(data);   }   
    }
```

Code for Getter

```
int wxfbIntegrationFrame::GetWidgetValue(wxString widget)
{
    long val;

        if (widget.compare("surveyvalue") == 0)
        {
            return surveynumber->GetValue();
        }
        else if (widget.compare("xoffset") == 0)
        {
            wxString data = apply_offset_x->GetValue();
            data.ToLong(&val);
            return val;
        }
        else if (widget.compare("yoffset") == 0)
        {
            wxString data = apply_offset_y->GetValue();
            data.ToLong(&val);
            return val;
        }
        else if (widget.compare("countdowntimer") == 0)
        {
            return timercount->GetValue();
        }
        else if (widget.compare("sensornumber") == 0)
        {
            wxString data = sensornumber->GetValue();
            data.ToLong(&val);
            return val;     
        }
        else if (widget.compare("temperatureselection") == 0)
        {
            return TempSelection->GetValue();       
        }
}
```

Comment: Use an `enum`? I think more information is required, such as where this string is coming from

Comment: 50+ "stringly typed" items? (*shudder*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be easily factoried through the use of an `unordered_map`

You just initialize it in your constructor :

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <functional>

class wxfbIntegrationFrame
{
public:
    wxfbIntegrationFrame()
    {
        _setters["hours"] = [this](const wxString &data) { this->hours->SetValue(data); };
        _setters["flowrateon"] = [this](const wxString &data) { this->flowrateon->SetValue(data); };
        ...

        _getters["hours"] = [this](int &data){ data = this->hours->GetValue();};


    }

    void SetWidgetValue(const wxString &widget, const wxString &data)
    {
        try
        {
            _setters.at(widget)(data);
        }
        catch (const std::out_of_range &err)
        {
            whatever you want to do
        }

    }

    int GetWidgetValue(const wxString &widget)
    {
        int data;

        try
        {
            _getters.at(widget)(data);

            return data;
        }
        catch (const std::out_of_range &err)
        {
            whatever you want to do
        }

    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void (const wxString &)> > _setters;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void (int &)> > _getters;
}
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that if being passed an invalid `widget` is likely, then a use of `find()` instead of `at()` may be more appropriate. The "unhappy" path should indeed be exceptional if we are paying for exception handling.

Comment: @underscore_d He didn't provided much context so I thought of using .at() even though this is not the most elegant way. Improvement is welcome, feel free to edit my answer

Comment: @rak007 in the constructor, where is data coming from? _setters["hours"] = [this](data) { this->hours->SetValue(data); };

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez this is a lambda function

Comment: @rak007 I tried to use your example. i get overloaded data is not a typename

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez fixed my example, should word. You should try to remove the try catch with the .find() function. I let you optimize the control flow ;)

Comment: @rak007 yes it is working now. could you add an example for getter too thanks.

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez this is another question. StackOverflow is not here to make your assignements. Yet this is pretty trivial, just change the return type of the std::function to whatever suits your needs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168289/discussion-between-rafael-gonzalez-and-rak007).